# Laravel previous and next recordings of the episode

Tags: php, laravel

is there any way to create previous and next recording of each episode on laravel?
this is what i have

My controller:

```
 public function getEpisode(Request $request, $movie, $slug, $id)
    {
        $movie = Movie::fromCache()->find($movie)->load('episodes');

        if (is_null($movie)) abort(404);

        /** @var Episode */
        $episode = $movie->episodes->when($id, function ($collection, $id) {
            return $collection->where('id', $id);
        })->firstWhere('slug', $slug);

        if (is_null($episode)) abort(404);

        $episode->generateSeoTags();

        $movie->increment('view_total', 1);
        $movie->increment('view_day', 1);
        $movie->increment('view_week', 1);
        $movie->increment('view_month', 1);

        $movie_related_cache_key = 'movie_related.' . $movie->id;
        $movie_related = Cache::get($movie_related_cache_key);
        if(is_null($movie_related)) {
            $movie_related = $movie->categories[0]->movies()->inRandomOrder()->limit(12)->get();
            Cache::put($movie_related_cache_key, $movie_related, setting('site_cache_ttl', 5 * 60));
        }

        return view('themes::themebptv.episode', [
            'currentMovie' => $movie,
            'movie_related' => $movie_related,
            'episode' => $episode,
            'title' => $episode->getTitle()
        ]);
    }
```

I have tried creating the previous and next buttons but it doesn't work at all. I hope someone can help me

Comment: If the Movie model is the entire series, and episodes are the individual movies, why don't you give these an order_id?

Comment: I don't know because I'm new to laravel. Is there any way to fix it and create the next and previous buttons? Thank you very much.